# How to create a popup window (PopupWindow) in Android

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

To create a simple working PopupWindow, we need to do the following:

**popup_example.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView         
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Test Pop-Up" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null, false),100,100, true);

pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

My requirement is that I need a

```
<TEXTVIEW android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

and a

```
<BUTTON android:id="@+id/end_data_send_button" android:text="Cancel"/>
```

in my `popup_example.xml`.  How can I handle these two components in my Java code?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Based on what you are showing, these probably should be a Dialog and not a PopupWindow.

Comment: ... now more than ever being that DialogFragments are available http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Hey, can i use the pop-up window to show an enlarged image(on click of the image) that is dynamically being shown in a listview? Thanks.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here, I am giving you a demo example. See this and customize it according to your need.

```
public class ShowPopUp extends Activity {
    PopupWindow popUp;
    boolean click = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        Button but = new Button(this);
        but.setText("Click Me");
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (click) {
                     popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
                     popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
                     click = false;
                } else {
                     popUp.dismiss();
                     click = true;
                }
            }
        });

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
        layout.addView(tv, params);
        popUp.setContentView(layout);
        // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
        mainLayout.addView(but, params);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
   }
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Any solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623908/how-to-make-one-corner-as-a-horn-like-structure-to-point-an-icon-in-android-stud

Answer (score 121):

## How to make a simple Android popup window

This is a fuller example. It is a supplemental answer that deals with creating a popup window in general and not necessarily the specific details of the OP's problem. (The OP asks for a cancel button, but this is not necessary because the user can click anywhere on the screen to cancel it.) It will look like the following image.

[image]

### Make a layout for the popup window

Add a layout file to `res/layout` that defines what the popup window will look like.

*popup_window.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#62def8">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="This is a popup window."/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Inflate and show the popup window

Here is the code for the main activity of our example. Whenever the button is clicked, the popup window is inflated and shown over the activity. Touching anywhere on the screen dismisses the popup window.

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {

        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);

        // create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        // dismiss the popup window when touched
        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That's it. You're finished.

## Going on

Check out [how gravity values effect PopupWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187508/3681880).

[image: PopupWindow bottom gravity with offsets]

You can also [add a shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50211489/3681880).

[image: PopupWindow with shadow]

### Further study

These were also helpful in learning how to make a popup window:

- [PopupWindow documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)
- [How To Create Pop Up Window In Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxqgtEewdfo) (YouTube video)
- [Android Popup Window Example](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-popup-window-example.html)

Comment: i don`t know why, but when i use method showAtLacation, my custom layout in inflater not working. Result such on your screenshot

Comment: @MartinezToni, I'm not sure why either.

Comment: very nice and thoughtful response!  thank you for posting this

Comment: context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); for accessing via public class. :)

Comment: what is the difference between a dialog and a popup window ??

Comment: `Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: Cannot use buttons/other clickable views with this, app crashed saying attempted to invoke virtual method on null object reference(NullPointerException)

Comment: Could you teach me how to inflate it on the certain object?

Answer (score 9):

are you done with the layout inflating? maybe you can try this!!

```java
View myPoppyView = pw.getContentView();
Button myBelovedButton = (Button)myPoppyView.findViewById(R.id.my_beloved_button);
//do something with my beloved button? :p
```

Answer (score 5):

I construct my own class, and then call it from my activity, overriding small methods like showAtLocation. I've found its easier when I have 4 to 5 popups in my activity to do this.

```
public class ToggleValues implements OnClickListener{

    private View pView;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private PopupWindow pop;
    private Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, blank;
    private ImageButton eraser;
    private int selected = 1;
    private Animation appear;

    public ToggleValues(int id, Context c, int screenHeight){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        pop = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(id, null, false), 265, (int)(screenHeight * 0.45), true);
        pop.setBackgroundDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alpha_0));
        pView = pop.getContentView();

        appear = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.appear);

        one = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.one);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.two);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.three);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        four = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.four);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        five = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.five);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        six = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.six);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.seven);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        eight = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.eight);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        nine = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.nine);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);
        blank = (Button) pView.findViewById(R.id.blank_Selection);
        blank.setOnClickListener(this);
        eraser = (ImageButton) pView.findViewById(R.id.eraser);
        eraser.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void showAtLocation(View v) {
        pop.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT, 40, 40);
        pView.startAnimation(appear);
    }

    public void dismiss(){ 
        pop.dismiss();
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        if(pop.isShowing()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getSelected(){
        return selected;
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0 == one){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(1);
        }else if(arg0 == two){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(2);
        }else if(arg0 == three){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(3);
        }else if(arg0 == four){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(4);
        }else if(arg0 == five){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(5);
        }else if(arg0 == six){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(6);
        }else if(arg0 == seven){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(7);
        }else if(arg0 == eight){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(8);
        }else if(arg0 == nine){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(9);
        }else if(arg0 == blank){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(0);
        }else if(arg0 == eraser){
            Sudo.setToggleNum(-1);
        }
        this.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you call this ToggleValues class from a button click action

Answer (score 4):

```
Button endDataSendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.end_data_send_button);
```

Similarly you can get the text view by adding a id to it.

Comment: @user746108 pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.text_view), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); TextView is only shown in the pop up..How can i fix the location of the button

Answer (score 4):

```java
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) SettingActivity.this.getSystemService(SettingActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.gd_quick_action_slide_fontsize, null),LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
pw.showAtLocation(SettingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.setting_fontsize), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
View v= pw.getContentView();
TextView tv=v.findViewById(R.id.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

This an example from my code  how to address a widget(button) in popupwindow

```
View v=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null, false);
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(v,500,500, true);
    final Button button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pw.showAtLocation(rootView.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


        }
    });
    final Button popup_btn=v.findViewById(R.id.popupbutton);

    popup_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score -3):

Edit your `style.xml` with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
```

`Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` provides a android *poup-up theme*