# Is it possible dismiss a PopupWindow from its button handler in a different activity?

Tags: android

I didn't architect this, but here's the situation : there is a PopupWindow with a button in it.  The button handler is in a **different activity** from the Activity that created the PopupWindow.  I want to know if there's a way to use the View param to the button handler to access the PopupWindow to have it *dismiss()* itself when I tap the button.

So far I've been able to use a series of *getParent()*'s to iterate up to the containing PopupWindow. But when I do it says it's a "PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer" (PopupWindow itself is not derived from View; it's derived from Object)

Is there any way I can use this to access the actual PopupWindow so I can call its *dismiss()* method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't architect this...

If you're working on it, then I suggest you (slightly) change the architecture to make it right.

Here is what I suggest: (I suppose the code for the handler is in another activity because these two activities can have the popup window?)

- Extract a base superclass for all the activities that can have the popup window, (make it `abstract`, and `extends Activity`, and all your concrete activities will extend that class), and put the handler code in this one.
- Keep a reference to the parent `PopupWindow` in that base activity, so you can always access it from the handler, or from anything else that might need it (keep that reference private to preserve encapsulation).

Comment: The code owners are really close a release deadline and don't want any architectural changes.    My marching orders are 'do it within the button handler IF it can be done there, else defer this to a future release.'    It's not obvious to me whether there's a way to do this in the handler so I'm just asking so I can decide whether to defer it.   Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I get it - So I don't know a "direct" way to get to the parent window, your way of using a series of getParent is probably a good try. Good luck with that ;)

Answer (score 0):

for Popup window there : duplicate [Popup Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/popupwindow-in-android) 
just see the solution for this.

and if you are talking about the dismiss();

public void dismiss ()

Dispose of the popup window. This method can be invoked only after `showAsDropDown(android.view.View)` has been executed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you're getting at or how this relates to my question.