# How to pop up a message that i will create in android

Tags: android

I want that if a button is clicked so a square will pop up in the bottom of the screen with title,message and buttons in the square(not a dialog).

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5945332/931982)

Comment: can I set the content view of the popupWindow something like 'popup.setContentView(R.layout.popup);'  ?