# How Can I make oncreate view as popup window in android?

Tags: android, popup

I am working with android.I am looking to display my oncreate view as a popup window instead of setcontent view. How Can I make On create view as popup window in android???

Comment: set `Theme` as a `Dialog` to your activity

Comment: You mean like a dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/popupwindow-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your activity tag in manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Then layout set with setContentView, it will be shown as Dialog