# How do i add popup window in listview when onclick of item using android studio?

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing listview with multiple widgets like textview, checkbox, imageview and spinner in one row of listview. Now i want to show pop up window when i click on any row of listview. How do i do ? 
following is my code, can you suggest me?

//MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView mListView;

private int[] startImages = new int[]{
        R.drawable.areaname,R.drawable.email,R.drawable.user};

private String[] mColorNames = new String[]{
        "1", "2", "3"};

private List<ListModel> listModelList = new ArrayList<>();
private String TAG = "Lokesh";

private PopupWindow popupWindow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    loadListWithImages();
    final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(listModelList,this);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: list"+listModelList.size());

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // String s = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           // String s = mListView.getSelectedItem().toString();


        }
    });
}


private void loadListWithImages() {
    for (int i = 0; i < startImages.length; i++) {
        ListModel listModel = new ListModel();
        listModel.setCount(0);
        listModel.setImage(startImages[i]);
        listModel.setName(mColorNames[i]);
        listModelList.add(listModel);
    }
}

//pop up window

private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {
        // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

     //   btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
    //    btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();

    }
};
```

}

//ListAdapter.java

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements android.widget.ListAdapter

```
{

    private List<ListModel> listModelList;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String TAG = "LokeshSA";
    private String[] mColorNames = new String[]{
            "1", "2", "3" };
    private String[] listitems=new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"};

public ListAdapter(List<ListModel> listModelList, Context mContext) {
    this.listModelList = listModelList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return listModelList.size();

}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listModelList.get(position);
}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //  ViewHolder holder = null;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_items, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        //checkbox

        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_cb);
        holder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        ListModel element = (ListModel) holder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.checkbox.setTag(listModelList.get(position));

        //spinner

        holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> startColorsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mColorNames);
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(startColorsAdapter);
        holder.spinner.setSelection(listModelList.get(position).getCount());



        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position2, long id) {
                ListModel starModel = listModelList.get(position);
                starModel.setCount(position2);
                listModelList.remove(position);
                listModelList.add(position,starModel);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // initialize image resource
    holder.iamge = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_imgs);
    // setting image
    holder.iamge.setImageResource(listModelList.get(position).getImage());

    //textview resource

     holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_tv);
     holder.textView.setText(listitems[position]);
     // holder.textView.setText(listModelList.get(position).getName());


    return convertView;
}
    private class ViewHolder{
        private Spinner spinner;
        private ImageView iamge;
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox checkbox;
    }



    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return getCount();
}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}


}
```

Comment: do you need any data from the list row you'll click??

Comment: no need of data

Comment: by popup do you mean a alert dialog box??

Comment: i want to show detail information of that row which i click using popup window or dialog box.

Comment: but just now you said you don't want any data from the row anyway share your ListModel class so that I can see what all are you populating in your listview

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your xml **screen_popup** ???

In MainActivity - call **initiatePopupWindow()** in mListView click as below

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // String s = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           // String s = mListView.getSelectedItem().toString();

    final TextView tv_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
    String txt = tv_id.getText().toString();//and pass the value("txt" to use it to display on dialog) as 

            initiatePopupWindow(txt);

        }
    });
```

You can also refer [popupwindow_stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987442/how-to-make-a-simple-android-popup-window)

Comment: i had tried above solution but not show any output, how to find position of row item which i click?

Comment: you will get the position on the method OnItemClick itself as int position, using that position you can get the values from the components present in corresponding row.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to get the data from the clicked list item use this code

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
    long id) {
        //to get the text from selected list item
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewbyId(R.id.listview_tv);
        String text = tv.getText().toString();

        initiatePopupWindow(text);

    }
});
```

Comment: It gives error at   TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewbyId(R.id.listview_tv);