# popup menu with scroll and edittext below

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, popupmenu

I've a screen with a button that is placed somewhere on the screen (near the top).

**I would like to click on the button and get this result:**
A menu is opened **right below** the button and lets you choose text(from the list) or write my own text(where "type here.." is written).

[image]

I've this popup menu:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, buttonChooseText);
    for (int i = 0; i < listDefaultText.size(); ++i) {
        // the list is from String type and contains "text1" and so on
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(listDefaultText.get(i);
    }
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getTitle().toString()) {
                case "Text1" :
                    //execute "text1" action
                    break;
                case "Text2" :
                    //execute "text2" action
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
```

So how can I get this result?

Comment: Why do you want to enter text, for search or adding item

Comment: if the user don't want any of the list (text1, text2...), he can write his own text. So if he presses on "Submit", I take this edittext string and display it somewhere else on the screen (not on the popup). and if he choose from the list, I take the text of the pressed item ("text1" and so on..) and display it somewhere.. Hope you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PopupMenu` will likely fall short to meet your requirement since it doesn't offer much of flexibility in terms of comprising views other than menu item. Use [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) instead as it supports custom layout. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987442/how-to-make-a-simple-android-popup-window) is an example of it.