# Add View into RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried to add view into `RecyclerView` when click to `Button` in a `ViewHolder`.

[image]

When click to `Button` in `ViewHolder3`, a View (view add more) will add and appear like image above.

`ViewAddMore` will pin there and `RecyclerView` can scroll normal.

I tried but don't found any solution for my issue;
Have any suggest for my issue?

Comment: so, where do u want to see that ViewAddMore ?

Comment: @Raghavendra: It's dynamically. When User click into `Button`, a ViewAddMore will appear above `ViewHolder1` and `ViewHolder2`.

Comment: I would suggest you not to do this. Its really bad design to block your recyclerViews view by one popup box.

Comment: I didn't get you can you tell me what is your exact issue?

Comment: @Raghavendra, phan-sinh is trying to (probably) keep the button even when user is scrolling on the screen.

Comment: @aa_oo thanks buddy

Comment: Yeap. `Button` in `ViewHolder3`. And after `Button` clicked, the `ViewAddMore` appear. When user scroll `RecyclerView`, the `ViewAddMore` do not disappear, It's will pin there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use PopupWindow to show this View.

```
// get a reference to the already created main layout
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout);

    // inflate the layout of the popup window
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    // show the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    // dismiss the popup window when touched
    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html
2. [How to make a simple android popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987442/how-to-make-a-simple-android-popup-window)

Hope this will help you.