# How to show dialog/popup application in kill state?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I want to show dialog/popup when application in kill state and `BroadcastReceiver` receive any action.

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       MyDialog.showDialog(context);
   }
}
```

I have added permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

I am getting exception when activity foreground

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My dialog is not display in activity kill state but receiver is called.

Comment: Before you think further . have a look into [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7918720/4168607) .  And if you still wanna go with dialog then [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269931/4168607) will help .Thx

Comment: I have tried but dialog is not show in foreground and kill state.

Comment: If you read the first link,  as its says it goes against Android design and UI guidelines then why don't you go with a Notification or a Activity with dialog theme. Its better if your app follow the guidelines and don't irritate user by a random popUp on screen.

Comment: Suppose you are making an app for client and you have to implement these type of things then you told them `it goes against Android design and UI guidelines`.

Comment: Yeah definitely.why not . Guidelines made by the technology for user experience, not by the client. Good bye

Comment: either client will be free to you or company will because it is done in other apps

Answer (score -2):

Actually, in this case, or without an activity, you can't launch any kind of dialog.

**1. First method**

create a dialog activity : [How to make dialog activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979631/5151608)

**2. Second**

create popup window: [How to make a simple android popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987442/how-to-make-a-simple-android-popup-window)

**Edit**

If the application is not in the foreground, **please don't do this**. Go for **notification**

Comment: I know How to show dialog and popups within activity, but I want to show it in `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: That I have already mentioned. You can't launch a dialog wihtout an activity context.

Comment: And in app kill state don't go for popup kid things, Its against design or ui guidlines

Comment: I have seen in multiple apps like whatsapp etc.

Comment: How you figured out that whatsapp is showing a Dialog not an Activity with DilogTheme?

Comment: These are the simple and best method if you want to do popup without activity context. Otherwise please elaborate what you want?