# How do i achieve a spinner with searchView from the screenshot below?

Tags: android

Finding it difficult to achieve the UI from the screenshot below. Searched but not getting exactly what I want.

[image]

Comment: You can create a Custom Adapter For Spinner . Or you can give [PopupWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/how-to-create-a-popup-window-popupwindow-in-android) a try .

Comment: Thank you @ADM but i'm new to android programing so the design looks quite complicated for me.

Comment: Then either try something simpler first (default spinner) or go through tutorials and read documentations to deepen your understanding

Comment: Alright, Andreas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want, you can use this awesome third-party library 
[Matterial Search View](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) to make search like thats. but if you keep want use Spinner, you can use custom adapter or populate menu to show suggest search word. thanks

Comment: Thank you, Yudi. Will check the library out and see if it fits what i'm looking for.