# Create a popup window with a next button when a user gives the right answer to my question in the quiz

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I am creating a quiz app where i want to make to create a popup window, when a user gives the right answer a popup should appear showing a text that he has given a right answer and a button. The button should move user to the next question in the app.

I tried to create a popup.xml which would respond when user gives the right answer.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#242424">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/correct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Correct! Go to Next."/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this method is called

```
public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {

        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);


        // create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);



        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);



        // dismiss the popup window when touched
        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I took help from some answers from [How to create a popup window (PopupWindow) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/how-to-create-a-popup-window-popupwindow-in-android) but it didn't got it right. Help me.

Here is the code after adding clicklistener in the onButtonShowPopupWindowClick() method

```
public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {

        // inflate the layout of the popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(level_one.this,level_two.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        // create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);



        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);



        // dismiss the popup window when touched
        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

The following trace shows crash on my app

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.geeksmind, PID: 18894
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.geeksmind.level_one.onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(level_one.java:180)
        at com.example.geeksmind.level_one$1.onClick(level_one.java:96)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's the issue? is it crashing or UI is not showing properly?

Comment: when I add a ClickListener for the next button in that method, it behaves abnormally and closes the current activity.

Comment: is it crashing ?

Comment: No. the whole app is not crashing. But the activity on which we are working is getting crashed.

Comment: Then put up  crash log

Comment: ok...i updated it in my question, have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the following line

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

As you are inflating a popupwindow and inside that `R.id.button3` is there. So parent of `R.id.button3`is popupwindow. The view initialization should look like below

```
View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
Button btn = popupView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
```