# How to show the custom dialog exactly down the clicked item item in a recycler view?

Tags: android-recyclerview, dialog

I've created a custom dialog & a recyclerview, and when i click an item in the recycler view my custom dialog appears but it just appears in the same place. How can i control it place exactly down the clicked item?

Comment: Use a `PopUpWidow` instead .

Comment: @ADM can u explain more? is PopUpWindow is an overrided function or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/how-to-create-a-popup-window-popupwindow-in-android